# Parameters for cmd_vel_mux

Tags: ros, controller-manager

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wish to adjust the priority of `cmd_vel_mux`
For this purpose I've located some `.YAML` files for understanding the syntax.

- name:        "Safe reactive controller"
  topic:       "safety_controller"
  timeout:     0.2
  priority:    10
- name:        "Keyboard operation"
  topic:       "keyboard_teleop"
  timeout:     0.2
  priority:    7

I can't figure out what is the exact meaning of these fields - name/topic/timeout/priority.
Of course "name" is a name... But in which namespace? Where do I set this namespace?
"timeout" is a measure of time, guessing - idle time while dealing with the callback, but what units? (second/milliseconds/minutes)
Priority - which is high, which is low? What is the maximum number of priorities available?
Topic - same as name. I do not know any of these topics, they are not available when listing the current topics (`rostopic list`), so I guess it is also another namespace (?)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241955/parameters-for-cmd_vel_mux/) by [meirela](https://answers.ros.org/users/27736/meirela/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-08-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @meirela !
The field topic should be filled with the full name of the input topic with also the namespace (i.e.: "/ns1/cmd_vel").
Timeout means for how much time the mux will latch the last command received if no incoming topics with different priorities are received. It should be in seconds.
Priority: this is easy; the higher the number filling the field, the higher the priority. I tried the node with five incoming topics, but I think you can set an arbitrary number of them.
Name: this field indicates whose incoming topic is being published by the multiplexer. This can be checked by subscribing to the output topic "/name/active".

Remember that the namespace of the output topic is the same of the  node's name.

---

Originally posted by [Chaos](https://answers.ros.org/users/15091/chaos/) with karma: 396 on 2016-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0